# Reading a file and print lines that contain a certain stream of characters decided by the user

Tags: c

Implement a program that receives the name of a text file and a format string via the command line format. A format string is a string that contains only three possible characters: `'V'`, which indicates a vowel, `'C'`, indicating a consonant and `'D'` indicating a digit.

The program will then have to read the file and print a video the lines that respect the format string.

Note: both uppercase and lowercase characters will be accepted from the format string; assume that the formed string and the lines of the file contain at most 500 characters.

**Example**

Assuming that the format string is `"VCD"` and the file contains:

```
2og  
Ok1  
Ok  
oK2
```

The program will print `Ok1` and `oK2` on the screen.

I've come up with this:

```
int main() {
  int x=1, i=0, flag=1, j=0;
  char str[500], n_file[100], formato[500],c;
  printf("\nInsert file name:\n");
  scanf("%s%*c",n_file);
  FILE *fr=fopen(n_file, "w");
  printf("\nTo quit from writing input 'quit'\n");
  while (x!=0) {
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    if (strcmp(str, "quit\n")==0) {
      x=0;
    }else{
      fputs(str,fr);
    }
  }
  fclose(fr);
  printf("\nInsert the format string (V for vowels, C for consonants and D for digits):\n");
  scanf("%s%*c",formato);
  printf("%s",formato);
  FILE *fp=fopen(n_file, "r");
  while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
    while (str[i]!='\n' && str[i]!='\0' && flag!=0 && formato[j]!='\n') {
      printf("\n%c",str[i]);
      if (formato[j]=='V') {
        if (str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='A' || str[i]=='E' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='i' || str[i]=='I' || str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='O' || str[i]=='u' || str[i]=='U') {
          flag=1;
          i++;
          j++;
          printf("\nPrimo if");
        }else{
          flag=0;
        }
      }else if (formato[j]=='C'){
        if ((str[i]>='b'-32 && str[i]<='z'-32) || (str[i])>='b' && str[i]<='z') {
          flag=1;
          i++;
          j++;
          printf("\nSecondo if");
        }else{
          flag=0;
        }
      }else if (formato[j]=='D') {
        if (str[i]>=0 && str[i]<=9) {
          flag=1;
          i++;
          j++;
        } else {
          flag=0;
          printf("\nTerzo if");
        }
      }
    }
    if (flag==1) {
      printf("\n%s",str);
    }
    j=0;
    i=0;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

The idea behind the code is: U compare each character in the format string first with vowels (I'm new to C so it's the only way i thought of doing the comparison, one by one for each vowel, capital or not), then I compare the consonants and then the digits.

If I have a `'V'` in the format string but the line does not have a vowel in that position the flag gets set to 0 and thus result in the exit of the 2nd `while` loop and the `str[]` line gets replaced with the next file line.

I've put some printfs in the 2nd while and I don't know why the 3rd if sets the flag to `0` even if the format string is `"VCD"` and I insert a digit as last character.

Comment: What is your actual question? Is the code working as expected? If not, in what way does it fail? What input do you provide, what output do you get, what output do you expect instead?

Comment: You should take a look at [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong). Also `switch` keyword would be useful.

Comment: i input what said in the text of the problem "so 2og ok1 Ok2 ok" and a format string as "VCD". So the program should print ok1 and Ok2 but what it does is it reads the 2 of 2og, compares it with V which is the firs character of the format line and sets the flag to 0 cause 2 is not a vowel but instead of going on with reading the next line the program stops

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this is one of those where I can tell you have put effort and thought into what you are trying to do, you are wisely trying to track the "state" of whether a match or mismatch occurs, and you are using `fgets()` to read line by line -- but then the train falls completely off the track.

The fact you are supposed to read from the file containing the strings and write to the "screen" makes opening a file to write with `"w"` and then reading from `stdin` a bit bewildering (though you could redirect from your file on `stdin` -- but why?)

But most of all you need to look at [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) for `while (!feof(fp))`.

That said, how do you approach a problem like this? You take it step-by-step and think about tackling the following problems:

- start by validating the number of arguments is what is needed,
- validate the format string is made up of only valid characters `'V'`, `'C'` and/or `'D'` (in any case),
- open your input file and validate it is open for *reading*,
- loop reading each line from your input file, conditioning your read-loop on the return from your read-function, e.g.  `while (fgets (line, size, fp)) { ... }`,
- check if the line matches the format string, if so, print it, if not, get the next line (you thought through this part correctly)

One other thought to help keep your logic straight, is to look at the steps and see if it would make sense to write a function to handle the task. This keeps your code tidy and prevents filling `main()` with an never ending jumble of code that is hard to follow.

For example, if you move the validation checks for if the user provided any bad characters in the format string to it's own function, and move the check whether each line matches the format to it's own function, your `main()` can be kept readable and easy to follow, e.g.

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  char line[MAXC+1], *fmt, *fname;    /* buffer for line, names for args */
  FILE *fp;                           /* file pointer for file stream */
  
  if (argc != NARG + 1) {   /* validate 2 arguments given (exe is always 1) */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: incorrect number of arguments, 2 required.\n"
                     "usage: %s str (max 3 chars 'V', 'C', 'D'), fname\n",
                     argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  
  fname = argv[1];    /* optional descriptive names for cmdline arguments */
  fmt = argv[2];
  
  if (bad_fmt_chars (fmt)) {  /* validate format string */
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!(fp = fopen (fname, "r"))) { /* open/validate file open for reading */
    perror ("fopen-fname");
    return 1;
  }
  
  while (fgets (line, MAXC + 1, fp)) {    /* loop reading each line */
    
    line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;       /* trim '\n' from line */
    
    if (!bad_line_fmt (line, fmt)) {      /* check line format */
      puts (line);
    }
  }
}
```

Adding the header includes, constants and function *declarations* used above to the top of the code, you would have a complete program absent the two functions *definitions* you need to write, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NARG        2   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC      500           /* max chars in line */
#define VALIDC   "VCD"          /* valid chars for str */
#define VOWELS   "AEIOUaeiou"   /* vowels */

/* function prototypes (declarations) */
int bad_fmt_chars (const char *str);
int bad_line_fmt (const char *line, const char *fmt);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  char line[MAXC+1], *fmt, *fname;    /* buffer for line, names for args */
  FILE *fp;                           /* file pointer for file stream */
  
  if (argc != NARG + 1) {   /* validate 2 arguments given (exe is always 1) */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: incorrect number of arguments, 2 required.\n"
                     "usage: %s str (max 3 chars 'V', 'C', 'D'), fname\n",
                     argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  
  fname = argv[1];    /* optional descriptive names for cmdline arguments */
  fmt = argv[2];
  
  if (bad_fmt_chars (fmt)) {  /* validate format string */
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!(fp = fopen (fname, "r"))) { /* open/validate file open for reading */
    perror ("fopen-fname");
    return 1;
  }
  
  while (fgets (line, MAXC + 1, fp)) {    /* loop reading each line */
    
    line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;       /* trim '\n' from line */
    
    if (!bad_line_fmt (line, fmt)) {      /* check line format */
      puts (line);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the two functions. How to check if the user entered any bad characters in the format string. While you can use a nested loop like you started to do, you can also use the `strchr()` function to replace the inner-loop since it can easily scan your string of allowable (valid) characters to see if the current character is found in it. (you can make it case insensitive by simply converting the current character to upper or lower case consistent with your definition of the valid characters) The use an required header for `strchr()` can be found in it man-page [man 3 strchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)<sup>1</sup>

When writing any function that can succeed or fail, or provides a informational return, choose an appropriate type for the function. For simple true/false returns (good/no-good, etc..), returning a simple `int` is fine. You can also include `stdbool.h` and return type `bool` in that case as well -- up to you.

Using a simple `int` return, returning `1` to indicate a bad character was found, or `0` if no offending characters were found -- and choosing a name that makes those returns make sense, you could do something like the following the validate the format string, e.g.

```c
/* check if format string has bad char not one of "VCD",
 * returns 1 if bad char found, 0 otherwise
 */
int bad_fmt_chars (const char *str)
{
  for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {      /* loop over chars in str */
    
    /* case insensitive char not in VALIDC, return err */
    if (!strchr (VALIDC, toupper(str[i]))) {
      fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid char '%c' is not one of \"VCD\".\n",
               str[i]);
      return 1;
    }
  }
  
  return 0;   /* return good (no bad chars) */
}
```

The function simply scans each character in the format string calling `strchr()` in a case insensitive way to check that each character is one of the `VALIDC` characters. It returns `1` immediately if an invalid format character is found, or `0` after scanning all characters.

Checking whether the line meets the format string can be handled in a number of different ways. One of the simplest is just to loop over each character read from the file and then use a `switch()` statement on the corresponding character from the format string to make sure the current character matches the format character. You can use the *case-fallthrough* aspect of a switch `case:` to do that in a case-insensitive way. (any `case` without a corresponding `break` falls through to the next `case`). So if you group both cases for `'V'` and `'v'` together without a break in the first, you will fall through to the second allowing you just to write the logic to handle a vowel once (same for consonant and digit).

What do you need to do for each character of input? Each character in `line` will have a corresponding format character in the format string. So for each character, you need to switch on the corresponding format character to determine if the current character is:

- a vowel if the format character is `'v'` or `'V'`,
- a consonant if the format character is `'c'` or `'C'`, or
- a digit if the format character is `'d'` or `'D'`.

Putting that together and using a `mismatch` flag to indicate where a mismatch in format is found, you could do something similar to the following:

```c
/* confirm each character in line matches format char in fmt,
 * returns 1 on any format mismatch or difference in length,
 * returns 0 if format matches exactly.
 */
int bad_line_fmt (const char *line, const char *fmt)
{
  int i = 0;      /* declare i to survive loop */
  
  /* both line and format chars must be available */
  for (; line[i] && fmt[i]; i++) {
    int mismatch = 0;
    /* case fall-through intentional */
    switch (fmt[i]) {
      case 'v': /* if not in VOWELS break loop */
      case 'V': if (!strchr (VOWELS, line[i])) { mismatch = 1; } break;
      case 'c': /* if in VOWELS break loop */
      case 'C': if (strchr (VOWELS, line[i]) || 
                    isdigit (line[i]) ||
                    ispunct (line[i]) ||
                    isspace (line[i])) { 
                  mismatch = 1;
                }
                break;
      case 'd': /* if not digit break loop */
      case 'D': if (!isdigit (line[i])) { mismatch = 1; } break;
    }
    
    if (mismatch) {   /* if mismatch between format and char */
      return 1;       /* return bad format */
    }
  }
  
  if (line[i] || fmt[i]) {  /* if either line or fmt not at end */
    return 1;               /* return bad format */
  }
  
  return 0;     /* return line matches format - return good */
}
```

(**note:** thanks to @Fe2O3 for finding the cases to `'c'` and `'C'` that I overlooked -- providing the point the extra eyes are always a benefit)

That is the completed program. You also always compile with *Full Warnings Enable* which means the compiler will complain about the case fallthrough. The compiler has an option to eliminate that warning (you telling the compiler, yes, case fallthrough was intentional). For gcc that option is `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough`. That allows you to compile your program with no warnings. Never accept code until it compiles without warning. Setting `-Werror` tells the compiler to treat warnings as errors (an easy way to keep yourself honest)

**Example Use/Output**

Does it work? With your input in the file `dat/formatvcd.txt`, the program produces the following output:

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "VCD"
Ok1
oK2
```

What about the case-insensitive format string?

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "VcD"
Ok1
oK2
```

How about matching other formats?

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "DVC"
2og
```

or

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "VC"
Ok
```

What about the format string check?

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "VqD"
error: invalid char 'q' is not one of "VCD".
```

What about a short format string?

```
$ ./bin/formatVCD dat/formatvcd.txt "V"
(no output)
```

Always try and test all cases you can think of to fully test your code. Even doing that, there are usually creative folks here that can point out cases you haven't considered.

If you have trouble putting the code together, let me know and I'm happy to post a completed version. All you need to do is paste the two functions below `main()` in the complete version of `main()` above. If you are compiling with `gcc`, you can use:

```
$  gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Werror -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -std=c11 -Ofast -o formatVCD formatVCD.c
```

To compile the executable to `formatVCD` from the source `formatVCD.c` with full warnings enable and treating warnings as errors. All modern compilers will have equivalent option, just check their documentation.

**footnotes:**

1. man pages are a bit cryptic when you first look at them, but they are very well written to give you the precise declaration, syntax, usage and any header or definitions required. Take a few minutes and make friends with the man-page format and then use them to lookup each function you use.

Comment: See, I knew it, the smart people here can always find a case you failed to test for `:)` Very true. Thank you! Let me go fix that.

Comment: @Fe2O3 - and no guarantee that that is the best way to fix it -- or that there are not more I don't see `:)` But, with your help the spaces, digits and punctuation won't slip by.

Comment: Glad to help. We all started programming at the same level, just keep at it. SO is a great resource. There are many, many very talented people here. Learning C is more of a journey than a race, so just take it slow and enjoy the learning. Good luck with your coding. (I guess not all at the same level -- you have the benefit of the internet and many many resources, there was no such thing when I started programming and you were lucky if you had dual-floppy drives `:)`

Comment: Magnificent! +1 for the explanation, +1 for flawlessness, +1 for entirety, +1 for comprehensiveness. The OP comment sums up the effort you have put on.

Comment: @H.S. - thank you for the kind words. I hadn't done a long one in a couple of weeks, so it was my turn.  (Fe2O3 - yes, early 8086 and 8088 had no hard drive -- if you only had one floppy drive, you would have to shuffle floppy disks -- you booted with a system disk, and then swapped and ran your code from a separate disk -- when your code made a system call -- you would have to swap the system disk back in, repeat) Before that it was all mainframes, tapes and punch-cards.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Wasn't aware of this comment of yours. My first "Hello world" was punched on paper-tape... Eventually moved on to 100Kb storage on a 10" floppy... Presently, with a (cheap!) micro-SD holding 256Gb, I can only say, "those were NOT the days" `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's amazing to think of the changes in the last 60 years. My oldest is about the graduate college in the EE world, while my earliest memories of electronics were going to the TV Repair shop to pickup a new glass tube transistor for the B&W console TV we had. (the very one I watched the moon landing on...) Fast forward 50+ years and I have 2 Picos chained together on a breadboard plugged into my laptop. Each pico has orders of magnitude more processing power than Apollo went to the moon on -- and costs $4. History will tell if it all was actual "progress", at times I wonder...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Just here to post a "pico-sized" answer to this OP... :-) Glad I can run the compiler immediately, instead of waiting for the overnight batch job to discover the intended semi-colon was a colon... (Appropriate anatomical term for the feeling one has the next day :-) Scroll down and marvel!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

@David Rankin has provided an OUTSTANDING answer to this OP. (Kudos Mr. Rankin!)

Because one should always strive for more, I'm posting my 'abbreviated' version of the algorithm. I didn't mess with files or command line arguments in order to focus on maximising the effectiveness of the code. Padding this out with validation (and perhaps some "data conditioning") would detract from its brevity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char *legit[] = {
        "",
        "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz",
        "0123456789",
        "AEIOUaeiou",
    };

    char *formato = "VCD";
    char *arr[] = { "2og","Ok1","Ok","oK2", };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ ) {
        char *str = arr[ i ];
        char *wnt = formato;

        while( *wnt && *str && strchr( legit[ *wnt>>1&3 ], *str ) )
            wnt++, str++;

        if ( !*str && !*wnt )
            puts( arr[ i ] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ok1
oK2
```

With nothing better to do, here's another alternative that doesn't have the overhead of function calls for each character being checked. (This is a custom version of the facilities of some of the "ctype" functions.) This version relies on the "format specifier string" being all upper case.

```
#define V 'V'
#define C 'C'
#define D 'D'
#define B 1
char tbl[] = {
    B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, 
    B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, 
    B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, 
    D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, B, B, B, B, B, B, 
    B, V, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, C, C, V, 
    C, C, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, C, C, B, B, B, B, B, 
    B, V, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, C, C, V, 
    C, C, C, C, C, V, C, C, C, C, C, B, B, B, B, B, 
};
#undef B
#undef D
#undef C
#undef V

int main() {
    char *formato = "VCD";
    char *arr[] = { "2og", "Ok1", "Ok", "oK2", };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ ) {
        char *str = arr[ i ];
        char *wnt = formato;

        while( *wnt == tbl[ *str ] )
            wnt++, str++;

        if ( !*str && !*wnt )
            puts( arr[ i ] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following is an alternative (and slightly compact) initialisation of `tbl[]` for use with the same code shown above.

```
char tbl[] = { // 'B'ad, 'V'owel, 'C'onsonant, 'D'igit
    "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDBBBBBB"
//                                                   0123456789
    "BVCCCVCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCBBBBBBVCCCVCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCVCCCCCBBBBB"
//    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
};
```

Comment: Alright, I'm intrigued by the indexing (or just not smart enough to snap to it), but what does shifting the 7-bit ASCII by `1` and anding with `3` do for me? I get it you cycle through `wnt` incrementing it, but anding with `b101`? (I'll have to go cipher on that a bit `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Turns out the ASCII values for 'c', 'd', 'v' yield 3, 4 and 6 in their low 3 bits... The shift changes that to 1, 2 & 3... Then, mask for the two LSBs... Thus the padding empty string at the top of the 4 element array... Just dumb luck exploited by this dummy... `:-)` (Your excellent answer included validating the "VCD" string! I would never have thought to do that...) `:-)`

Comment: Ahh. That would have taken me a bit to get to. First thought was bit-6 is the case-bit, so shifting by one? Then, well that doesn't apply to the index for `legit` anyway -- so I was still scratching my head. Thanks. That's a great way to sneak the case insensitivity in -- though it may need a comment in the code.  Went right over my head on first look `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And, another version that would run faster... `:-)` Many, MANY ways to skin a cat `:-)`